# Один групповой раннер или несколько на каждый репозиторий?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-runner, ci-cd

Есть условно 5 проектов на гитлабе, все они в одной группе, и все они работают на одном сервере. Как более правильно использовать ci/cd, создать раннер под каждый проект или создать один раннер, обслуживающий всю группу?

Comment: Как по мне под каждый проект свой ранер и настроить возможность одновременного запуска 3-5 штук(не экспертное мнение)

Answer (score 0):

Мы используем один раннер на десятки репозиториев, потому что чаще всего изменения в коде не происходят параллельно, а если и происходят, то ожидают своей очереди.

Больше раннеров, больше потребляется ресурсов сервером.

У нас несколько раннеров для разных команд.

Если у вас есть возможность использования несколько раннеров и мало проектов и вы часто запускаете CI/CD, то они обеспечат вам более скорый результат, чем ожидание в очереди одного раннера.

У нас более 30 репозиториев, с 4 самыми активными (ежедневно вливаются изменения и несколько раз в день). Для них используется 1 раннер.

P.S. Я не DevOps, а пользователь GitLab в качестве разработчика. Жить с одним раннером можно, но бывает нужно ждать пару минут.